# $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{C}-{0}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove that $\mathbb{C}/ \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ holds.

I`m using this theorem: 
If $\phi: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}-{0}$ is a homomorphism and $H=Ker(\phi)$, with $H$ as a normal subgroup for $\mathbb{C}$. Then, $\mathbb{C}/ \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{C}-{0}$ if $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism.

My attempt:

I try to find an homomorphism $\phi:  \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}-{0}$, but I can`t seem to find it. Any help would be really welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try $$\phi(z)=e^{2 \pi i z} .$$

Comment: but that is only for the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}-{0}$, I need to get values mapped to the whole of $\mathbb{C}-{0}$.

Comment: @Pimziengs If $z$ is complex $e^{2 \pi i z}$ is not necessarily on the unit circle. Try setting $z=-i$ for instance.

Comment: Aw, I see thanks!